# crontab not running php script

Tags: php, debian, cron

crontab was at one point running properly but one day after running it deleted its file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.DYqvRY/crontab installed on Thu Mar 17 14:50:32 2016)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0 0 1 * *  /var/www/html/mail.php

0 0 16 * *  /var/www/html/mail.php

0 13 2 * * /var/www/html/mailcheck.php

0 13 17 * * /var/www/html/mailcheck.php

0 13 2 * * /var/www/html/mailcheckadmin.php

0 13 17 * * /var/www/html/mailcheckadmin.php

0 0 1 * *  /var/www/html/PaymentPeriod_Create.php

0 0 16 * *  /var/www/html/PaymentPeriod_Create.php

* * * * * /var/www/html/testsession.php  > /var/www/html/log
```

I am using `# crontab -e` to edit this file then when i'm done I press ^X Y ENTER
is there any extra step that i am missing `* * * * * /var/www/html/testsession.php  > /var/www/html/log` this should run every minute right?

Comment: This runs every minute: `*/1 * * * * /var/www/html/testsession.php  > /var/www/html/log`

Comment: @Daan I changed that line but still the script is not running

Comment: @Daan why `*/1 * * * *` rather than `* * * * *`? Are they equivalent? I always use `* * * * *` to run something every minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `* * * * * /var/www/html/testsession.php  > /var/www/html/log` is valid.

Most likely since it is the final line in the crontab it is missing the newline. Cron requires a newline at the end of every entry; in other words your crontab must finish with an empty line.

From the "Diagnostics" section of `man crontab`:

> cron requires that each entry in a crontab end in a newline  character. If  the  last entry in a crontab is missing the newline, cron will consider the crontab (at least partially) broken and refuse to install it.

You may want to replace the `>` with a `>>` so that new content is appended to the log file rather than overwriting it every minute, ie `* * * * * /var/www/html/testsession.php  >> /var/www/html/log`. This will still create the log file if it is not already present.

Your PHP file will also need the execute bit set and will need to start with `#!/usr/bin/php` (or the path to PHP on your system) on the first line. Alternatively you could replace the cron line with `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/testsession.php  >> /var/www/html/log` to explicitly use the PHP interpreter to execute the script.